# Video Create from a Image using avconv

Tags: image, ubuntu, avcodec

I want create a video from a image,my code is

```
avconv -f image2  -i test2.jpg  -s 320X240 -r 30  -pix_fmt yuv420p -qmin 10 foo.mpg
```

But I got a error

```
VBV buffer size not set, muxing may fail
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: @ElefantPhace Can you link to the duplicate?